# Knockout.JS Array - trying to reset array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

So here is the project I am working on at Github: https://github.com/joelt11753/Udacity-map

In this program, I have a menu that is created from a list.  I am filtering this menu using a HTML select element. By default, everything is displayed.  When another option is selected, the menu will change.  The problem at the moment is that I need to reset the menu list every time the filter is run.

Look at the app.js file, it is in the js folder.  On line 8 there is a computed observable that filters the menu.  Notice that on line 10, I reset the viewList() to be empty.  It needs to be empty so I can start fresh and filter according to the users selection.  However, line 10 only works when the default option is selected.  The default is the "if" on line 11.  Line 20 starts the block that displays the filtered menu.  The console.log on line 21 displays the correct number, but there is no reset occurring.  Basically, my question is, why does the reset not work every time a selection is made?  If you try the app, when you select a different option, other than the default, the menu should become empty.  But, it isn't.

Thanks guys!

Comment: You can clear array like this in javascript arr= [1,2,3,4]; arr.splice(0)..

Comment: Cool, so that one works.  But, why isn't setting the array to empty, such as = []; working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with how you reset the array. This

```
this.viewList = [];
```

will not work. Why? Becase think what `viewList` is initially. It is a `ko.observableArray`. But you are assigning a plain array therefore losing any functionality provided by the `observableArray`. The correct way to clear it is this:

```
this.viewList.removeAll();
```

Note that you don't assign the value of this expression back to `viewList`. That is because `removeAll` mutates the collection itself instead of creating a new collection. Also consider declaring a permanent reference to the object as such:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    ...
}
```

It is a general good practice because of the fact that the object `this` points to may change. But this way, you are creating a 'snapshot' of it as it was at the time of object creation, in other words, the created object itself. Back to your question, if you use `viewList.removeAll()`, the elements displayed underneath the dropdownlist will properly change. Because I don't know where the items to be displayed should come from (since you only wrote a `console.log` into the `else`˙branch), check this, and update your question if there are any more problems left.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.splice();
```

This will return you empty array.